# Is there a way for pymc3 to raise an exception when target_accept is not met?

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

I am currently running sampling and training models in a loop. and i wish to skip over those when they do not meet the target_except requirement. is this possible?

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using jitter+adapt_diag...
Multiprocess sampling (4 chains in 4 jobs)
NUTS: [defs_star, atts_star, intercept, sd_def_log__, sd_att_log__, home]
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2000/2000 [02:31<00:00, 13.21it/s]
There were 5 divergences after tuning. Increase `target_accept` or reparameterize.
The acceptance probability does not match the target. It is 0.227249509897, but should be close to 0.8. Try to increase the number of tuni
ng steps.
The gelman-rubin statistic is larger than 1.05 for some parameters. This indicates slight problems during sampling.
The estimated number of effective samples is smaller than 200 for some parameters.
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3000/3000 [00:06<00:00, 467.94it/s]
[8, [56]]
```

**EDIT**

I do not want to change the parameters or tune the model currently. That will be in another question.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two ways of doing this: The first is the "blessed" way, which is not very flexible right now.

```
with pm.Model():
    ...
    trace = pm.sample()

trace.report.raise_ok()
```

This will raise a `ValueError` for divergences or bad tuning, but it is fairly new, so you can't yet specify types of divergences easily.

Another way that is much less stable is, with the same `trace` object as above,

```
from pymc3.backends.report import WarningType


if any(w.kind is WarningType.BAD_ACCEPTANCE for w in trace.report._warnings):
    raise SomeCustomError(w.message)
```

The `_warnings` attribute is marked as private and may change in the future, but can give you more flexibility in accessing the convergence statistics.